Statistical test for comparing PCA variation between two groups
I have conducted a Procrustes transformed PCA. I have data from multiple ancient human populations transformed onto the same background of modern reference data.
I have a few populations that I am investigating and I notice that there is a clear difference in variability from looking at covariance confidence ellipses
(e.g., see A and B from figure below). I am looking for some kind of statistical test to establish this, so that I can be certain it is not simply due to sample size or any other biasing factors.
Levenes' test? Bartlett's?

Figure from Vyas, Koncz, et al. 2023

You want a test for what is called, at least in ecology, multivariate dispersion.  There is a multivariate generalization to Levene's test that is available in the Vegan package in R as the betadisper function.
